# How to add faded view when i start editing the text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create view like the image below.
My implementation should use text field input ,the behavior i like to built is once i clicked on the text input the current view should be faded because once the user start typing i will show table for autocomplete?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to set a `UITextFieldDelegate` for your `UITextField`.

In the `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method, you can just set the alpha of your main view to someting like 0.7. Or you can add another black `UIView` object with alpha 0.7 on top of your main view.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the search bar provided by the iOS SDK ? It contains everything you need and will act as shown on the screenshot...
If you don't want it, then @ugur answered you

Comment: because i have two text fileds in my case so it will complex the solution if i used two search bars